# Put me on display

Tags: phrases

What does mean `put me on display`?

I have heard that in the song You don't own me from Grace:

> Don't tell me what to do
>
> And don't tell me what to say
>
> Please, when I go out with you
>
> Don't put me on display

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's a line from "You Don't Own Me" (originally [popularized by Lesley Gore](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vNb-8gLcXLs) in 1964).

To put someone (most often a woman) "on display" in this context is to show her off as a trophy. The implication is that she is a "prize" the man has "won" (and therefore, in a way, owns).

Cf. [trophy wife](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trophy_wife)

Comment: +1 for props to La Gore (extra credit if you add John Madera and David White to the answer...)